# How to get the maximum value of the same columns from two dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframe, df1 and df2 as below. I am trying to create a new dataframe that will show the maximum score for each student across subjects. For example, in the new dataframe, the match_score for George would be 63 (which is the maximum match_score in df1 and df2).

Is there a way to do this? Any advices and suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = { 'student':['George','Andrea','micheal','Ann',
        'maggie','Ravi','Xien','Jalpa'],
'match_score':[63,42,56,70,38,78,84,99],
'ela_score':[43,74,41,82,69,46,70,98]}


df2 = { 'student':['George','Andrea','micheal', 'Matt',
        'maggie','Ravi','Xien','Jalpa'],
'match_score':[62,47,55,74,32,77,86,77],
'ela_score':[45,78,44,89,66,49,72,73]}

df1=pd.DataFrame(df1)
df2=pd.DataFrame(df2)
```

Comment: Would you want to return the ela_score column as well, or just the match_score maximum?

Comment: Yes, in the real work situation, I have more than 20 subjects, I would like to return the maximum score for all subjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`Groupby.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html):

```
In [1293]: df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby(level=0).max()

In [1294]: df
Out[1294]: 
   student  match_score  ela_score
0   George           63         45
1   Andrea           47         78
2  micheal           56         44
3     Matt           74         89
4   maggie           38         69
5     Ravi           78         49
6     Xien           86         72
7    Jalpa           99         98
```

Comment: can you please share what is the level=0 means, thank you!!!

Comment: `groupby(level=0)` means grouping on the first index. Since here there's only one index, it is grouping on it.

Comment: Thanks Mayank a lot for this. May I ask if max function only works for either integer or float but not string? I notice in the file, there is NA value that makes the entire columns becomes object and max() does not return the correct value but NA

Comment: In case there's a string `NA`, do you want to treat it as `null` and ignore it from max calculation?

Comment: if one has NA but another has 70, the returned value needs to be 70. I got stuck at this and would be greatly appreciated for your guidance

Comment: I figured out a way, which is to replace all 'NA' with '0' in order for max to return the correct value. Thanks Mayank again.

Answer (score 1):

---

```
data=pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

---

```
data.match_score.max()
```

99